# Jquery template anchor tag click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates

SO i have this jquery template and i need to call a jquery or javascript function on the click of this anchor tag. Ive tried it a few different ways.

```
<a href="yourfunction()"
```

Ive tried

```
$('#number').click(function(e){
```

So if anyone could help it would be highly appreciated. The anchor tag in question is the phone number one with the id of number.

```
   @model OpenRoad.Web.Areas.Marketing.Models.MobyNumberSelectionModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Moby Number Selection";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section scripts {
<script type ="text/javascript">


        $('#number').click(function (e) {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
    mixpanel.track("View Marketing | Moby | Number Selection");
    //$(document).on("click", "#number", function (e) {
    //    event.preventDefault();
    //    alert('test');    });
    //$('#number').click(function (e) {
    //    Alert('test');
    //});
</script>
    }

<label class="lgform" style="text-align: left; padding: 10px 0;">Select state and area code:</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, OpenRoad.Web.Helpers.DropDownLists.GetOptionValues("States", Model.State),
new { @class = "ddtrigger", data_url = "/Marketing/Moby/GetAreaCodes", data_template = "areaCodeTemplate", data_target = "AreaCode" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AreaCode, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["AreaCodes"],
    new { @class = "ddtrigger", data_url = "/Marketing/Moby/GetPhoneNumbers", 
        data_template = "phoneNumberTemplate", 
        data_target = "phoneNumbers", 
        data_listtarget="true" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MobyNumber)
<script id="areaCodeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
    <option value="${AreaCode}">${AreaCode}</option>
</script>
<br />
<script id="phoneNumberTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
    <div class="numberselectbox">
        <strong>${FormattedPhoneNumber}</strong>   <a href="#" id="number"  class="rowSelection btn_simple" data-url="/Marketing/Moby/SelectPhoneNumber" data-redirect="/Marketing/Moby" data-value="${PhoneNumber}">Select</a><br/>
    </div>
</script>
<div id="phoneNumbers">
</div>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using and do you call the `$('#number').click(..)` function after or before you add your `a` tag to the HTML?

Comment: `$('#number').click(function(e){` is the preferred way, but it must be applied after the template has been rendered and appended to the DOM.

Comment: i added the entire view to the question so your questions should be answered.

Comment: aand my jquery isnt updated enough for the on keyword

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a template to generate the elements, these elements will be dynamic so you need to use delegated event model.

Also since it is a template, do not use static id for the elements since the elements can be duplicated - use class attribute instead

```
<script id="phoneNumberTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-template">
<div class="numberselectbox">
    <strong>${FormattedPhoneNumber}</strong>   <a href="#"  class="number rowSelection btn_simple" data-url="/Marketing/Moby/SelectPhoneNumber" data-redirect="/Marketing/Moby" data-value="${PhoneNumber}">Select</a><br/>
</div>

$(document).on('click', '.number', function(){
    //do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try jQuery's `on()` method or `click()` shorthand:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     $('#number').on('click', function(e){
         // your method implementation here
         e.preventDefault();
     });
     // OR //
     $('#number').click(function(e){
         // your method implementation here
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` will be needed to stop the default action from being triggered

Comment: @dcodesmith Cheers, edited my answer to include `e.preventDefault();`